# In "I saw the women crying" would femina be accusative?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, grammar-choice

If you translate "I saw the women crying" would it be feminas with the accusative?  The women are both the object of the seeing and the subject of the crying which is confusing me. I am new to Latin.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The trick is, in Latin, it's the subject of a *finite verb* that's nominative. The subjects of other types of verbs, like infinitives and participles, don't have to be. (Linguistically, those other types of verbs *don't assign nominative case*).

So the case of *fēminae* here depends on which verb is the finite one. You could phrase it in a few different ways:

> Videō fēminās lacrimantēs
> *I see (the crying women).*

Here, "crying" is a participle, while "I see" is finite.

> Videō fēminās lacrimāre
> *I see (the women to be crying).*

Similarly here "crying" is an infinitive, while "I see" is finite again. (This isn't how we'd usually phrase it in English, but it's the same construction as "I expected the women to be crying"; Latin uses that construction with more verbs than English does.)

> Fēminae vīsae lacrimant
> *(The women being seen) are crying.*

Here, on the other hand, "seeing" is the participle, while "are crying" is the finite verb, so the women become nominative.

Or, if all else fails, you can use two finite verbs! In this case, "women" needs to have two separate cases—so what do you do?

The answer is, you need to add in a pronoun to take the other case. (Specifically a *relative pronoun*, like "who" or "which" in English.)

> Fēminae quās videō lacrimant
> *The women, whom I see, are crying.*

Here, "women" is nominative as the subject of "are crying", while "whom" is accusative as the object of "I see". Or you could do it the other way around.

> Videō fēminās quae lacrimant
> *I see the women, who are crying.*

Now "women" is accusative and "who" is nominative.

This is the most flexible way to have a noun fulfill multiple roles, since you can do it with *any* roles, not just subjects and objects. (You can't use a participle for "the women who I was running with", for example.)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: As for the example _Videō fēminās lacrimantēs_, I was wondering why you decided to give the translation of the **attributive** reading of _lacrimantes_ ('I see the crying women').  In the context of the OP's question, I understand that the (more) relevant reading of _lacrimantes_ is rather the **predicative** one ('I see the women crying'). It could then be useful to point out that this example is ambiguous in this sense.

Comment: @Mitomino Mostly because I wanted to emphasize the differences in syntax in the English translations. But that's a fair thing to note.